# Firebase Auth lastSignInDate and creationDate comparison failure

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

First of all what I need in this case is knowing that this is the very first user's login (log in-after-sign up also counts as first) so I can add them to the database. For this purpose I have this check:

```
func isNewUser(userMetadata: UserMetadata) -> Bool {
    return userMetadata.creationDate == userMetadata.lastSignInDate && !UserDefaults.standard.hasLoggedIn
}
```

I need the `UserDefaults` check because creationDate and lastSignInDate will be equal till the moment the user logs out.

Everything worked perfectly till today when I get these strange logs:

```
(lldb) po userMetadata.creationDate
▿ Optional<Date>
  ▿ some : 2019-02-06 21:18:15 +0000
    - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 571180695.0

(lldb) po userMetadata.lastSignInDate
▿ Optional<Date>
  ▿ some : 2019-02-06 21:18:15 +0000
    - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 571180695.1040001
```

Dates look the same but the check for equality fails.

The code where I call `isNewUser`:

```
authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [unowned self] (auth, user) in
   if let firebaseUser = user, Auth.auth().isNewUser(userMetadata: firebaseUser.metadata) {
       self.handleNewUser(firebaseUser)
   }
}
```

The documentation does not say much about first logins. I know there is a `isNewUser` property in `AdditionalUserInfo` class but I don't know how I can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

This might be related to some backend changes, which we're looking into. For the moment you could round down the value of `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` before the comparison.

But it's better to use [`AdditionalUserInfo.newUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAdditionalUserInfo#newuser) for this check these days. You get that from [`AuthDataResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult), so straight after the user signs in like for example with [`signIn(withEmail:password:completion:)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#signinwithemailpasswordcompletion). In FirebaseUI you can also get the `AuthDataResult` as shown here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/Auth#sign-in

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I was also looking at both your suggestions. But how would I use `signIn(withEmail:password:completion:)` when I am using Firebase UI with Facebook, Google and Mail login?

Comment: You wouldn't. So that only leaves the first option for now.

Comment: I added some more options to my answer, including how to get the `AdditionalUserInfo` when using FirebaseUI. I also just found out that the `additionalUserInfo.isNewUser` always returns false *if signing in with a passwordless email-link*. If you use that, please upgrade to SDK version 5.3.1 when that comes out (since that will contain a fix for the bug).